# Processing Minim Library execution of Jar file

Tags: jar, processing, audio, minim

I have not been able to execute a jar file in Processing when using the minim sound library. Has anyone else encountered this problem or know why it may be occurring? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Never had a problem with that.
Can you try this in Processing: **Sketch > Import Library... > minim** ?

Comment: Yes I tried that and it still gave the error that it cold not find the main class and the program will exit?

Comment: What version of Processing are you using and what operating system ?

Comment: I have tried both 1.2 and 1.5, and I am running a Windows operating system.

Comment: I've installed XP and Processing 1.5.1 and tried creating a new sketch  which uses Minim and it worked. Do you get any error messages when you simply paste this `import ddf.minim.*;
import ddf.minim.signals.*;` into a new sketch ? Also, can you confirm that you have Minim .jar files in they're default location (`C:\Program Files\processing-1.5.1\modes\java\libraries\minim\library`)?

Comment: No my Processing 1.5.1 was on my desktop I tried moving it into C and for some reason the library would not import. I think that you are right with the problem may be the location of Processing.

Comment: I see. It's a bit tricky to guess what the actual problem is, but try 'reinstalling' it: 1. Download the software 2. Unpack it (somewhere like C:\Program Files) 3. Run a Minim sample from the Examples 4. If 3 works, create a new sketch, add this line: `import ddf.minim.*;` and test if it work...if does, you're all setup, otherwise, post any error message you get.

Comment: "No" as in you don't get any errors when doing the minim imports or "no" the minim library jars aren't in the Processing folder ?